# Gatling pass data from feeder to exec

Tags: scala, gatling

Could you help me how to get data from feeder in exec block? When I use exec with session input parameter is not a problem, but when I want to use with ActionBuilder I don't know how to do it. Documentation says to use Gatling EL, but seems it can be use only with http protocol. I want to use gRPC protocol, so I can't use methods http().

Do you have any idea how to do it?

My code:

```
def runAction : ActionBuilder = {
    //TODO how to get parameter1 and parameter2 from session or feeder here.

  }

 def getRandomData() = Map("parameter1" -> UUID.randomUUID.toString, "parameter2" -> (Random.nextInt(100000) + 700000))

  val feeder = Iterator.continually(getRandomData())

scenario("TestGRPC server")
    .feed(feeder)
    .exec(session => {
      val parameter1= session("parameter1").as[String] //here is works
      val parameter2= session("parameter2").as[Int] //here is works
      println("parameter1: " + parameter1+ "parameter2: " + parameter2) //print diffrent for each execution
      session
    })
    .exec(runAction)

setUp(
    grpcScenario.inject(
      constantUsersPerSec(2) during (durationInSeconds seconds))
  ).protocols(grpcConfig)
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the [gatling-grpc documentation](https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc), the payload can indeed take an expression.

which means you should be able to have code like this in 'runAction'

```
grpc("request name")
.rpc(rpc.method)
.payload("parameter1: ${parameter1}")
```